# MySQL Query doesn't work PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$result = mysql_query("
    select CashID,something,something1,something2 
    from MsUser mu, MsCash mc 
    where mu.UserID = mc.UserID and (something2 = 1 or something2 = 2)");

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false)){
    This doesn't works
}
```

CashID is in MsCash, UserID is in MsUser and MsCash. Why it doesn't work on PHP? It works when try to take only one table, but when its get joined, mysql_fetch_array return me an error.

```
$resultLog = mysql_query("
    select UserID from MsUser where username=$username and password=$password 
    ");

while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultLog) !== false)){
    //This works
}
```

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given ...

I have tried this in a blank page

```
<?
include "connect.php";

$result = mysql_query("
    select CashID,something,something1,something2 
    from MsUser mu, MsCash mc 
    where mu.UserID = mc.UserID and (something2 = 1 or something2 = 2)");
if($result === false){
    echo 'Query error: '.mysql_error();
}else{
    echo "works";
}
?>
```

but it give me nothing, also the echo doesn't show too.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work in PHP? It would help to post the PHP code you are using, or at least the error you are getting.

Comment: Have you tried running this directly in MySQL?  Do you get an error?  If so, what's the error?

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN MsCash mc ON mu.UserID = mc.UserID WHERE (something2 = 1 or something2 = 2)`

Comment: because I used it on PHP. The error I get is
"Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given ..."

Comment: ^--< then that's most likely a connection issue.

Comment: I used this for connection

   $host="localhost"; // Host name.
   $db_user="root"; // MySQL username.
   $db_password=""; // MySQL password.
   $database="myDatabase"; // Database.
   mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password);
   mysql_select_db($database);

I can access the database, because I have to login before I execute that query.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: This is generally bad workflow. You should test, what `mysql_query` returns before passing it to a function, which works with results (e.g. `mysql_fetch_array`), because `mysql_query` can return `false` on error. If it returns `false`, use a function `mysql_error` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe that something is a reserved word.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Sidenote: You have `while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){` which has one `(` too many. Do `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){` @LazuardyKamil

Comment: @Fred -ii-: both is nonsense. He knows, what's the error, so he has clearly displaying errors enabled. Parentheses you can use as many as you want, if they are paired.

Comment: Ok, so it's nonsense. However, the extra bracket isn't. @DawidFerenczy no one pointed it out, so how's the OP supposed to know?

Comment: Please, try to do what I have advised to see, what's wrong.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: if he would have wrong parentheses, he would get **parse error**. That's not a case, because he got *Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given*.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy HUH????? slap that thing in your IDE, see what the bracket count will be. In other words, you're telling me that `while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){` is valid.

Comment: No, I'm telling you, that he has NOT **parse error**, so he has parentheses right in his code. Don't invent errors he doesn't have. He clearly posted, what his error.

Comment: 3x `(` and 2x `)` isn't a match, not in my books anyway. Ok, I'm outta here.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: try to read his question. There is his error message described. If he can see error, you don't have to advise him enabling error displaying. If he don't have a parse error, you don't have to advise him to correct parse error. That's all.

Comment: no no no, Its just my misstype here, in my actual code, there is no error in it, so its nearly impossible when if I miss the brackets.

Comment: @Lazuardy Kamil: consult it with PHP manual! `mysql_error` **returns** an error message, it **does NOT print it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CashID,something,something1,something2
FROM MsUser mu
LEFT JOIN MsCash mc ON mu.UserID = mc.UserID
WHERE something2 = 1 or something2 = 2
```

Comment: and its still error :(

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given ...

Comment: That query is syntactically right. Test what `mysql_query` returns and use the function `mysql_error` if it returns `false` to see what's wrong.

Comment: but the weird thing is I can access database for login which I include the same file 'connect.php' in my login page.

Comment: Have you tried checking if mysql_connect() returns false?

Comment: Now it's case closed. Its because ambiguous column. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: @CullyLarson: he would get different error on failed connection.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy You're right.  I realized it after posting, but it's such a stupid question I didn't feel concerned about changing it  :)